# Where do I find the bpl file after I compile a package?

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe3, jedi, jvcl

I want to create *.bpl file but I am failing to do so.
Specifically, I am trying to make JEDI plugins, but I have tried an empty pure Delphi package, too.

If I create a new package in Delphi XE3, I get an empty unit - if I "make" this project called "Package1.bpl", I get a .dcu file in "debug/win32/", but no .bpl file.
No error is reported by the compiler.

An empty JEDI plugin (bpl-style) only gives a .dcu, too, while an empty dll-style JEDI plugin gives a .cdu **and** a .dll file in "debug/win32/".

This is the first time I am trying to make a new package, so I am completely lost.
What am I missing?

Comment: Are you looking for file/new/package and adding units?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to the `Tools` menu and navigate to `Environment Options` -> `Delphi Options` -> `Library`.
There you find the `Package Output Directory` and the `DCP Output Directory`. These directories are the default output directories for BPLs and DCPs, so the bpl will be created if your packages is compiled, but in a different directory from what you expect.

The JEDI plugins probably have their output directory configured otherwise in `Project` -> `Options`.

Answer (score 0):

For those that don't want to travel into Delphi IDE/options etc, lately in Delphi XE it's something like this:

"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Bpl;"

Your exact folder might be different based on 17.0

These folders also end up in the path environment variable of your system, bit dangerous and can lead to some mighty magic loading confusion ?!

"How's that BPL still loading after it was deleted from my local project folder ?" :)

Another solution is to add "." to your project settings without the "". Prevents you from having to modify your delphi environment options/settings, something you probably never want to do since JEDI and other projects may rely on these default settings to function properly. Only change it if you know what you are doing and how to correctly make JEDI and others work if it was changed, this may get tricky/hairy, probably requires search paths to be added.